# What are zero width independent subexpressions in regexes?

Tags: regex, pcre

So I was looking for a complete cheat sheet for PCRE's (still haven't found one, bonus points if you can show me one, I haven't managed to find one that contains both \K and \G) and I stumbled across [this old one](http://www.bitcetera.com/page_attachments/0000/0030/regex_in_a_nutshell.pdf).

Now I am familiar with the lookaround assertions such as `(?<!somestuff)` or `(?=otherstuff)` but I had not come across this construct (from linked to article):

> (?>…) zero-width independend[sic] subexpression

Could someone explain what this does, and when it is useful to use?

Additionally could point me to documentation that contains all the special symbols in PCRE's? [ruby's docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/regexp_rdoc.html) don't even cover all the features that they have in their regexes:

```
[1] pry(main)> /hello\Kworld/.match("helloworld")
=> #<MatchData "world">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?>...)` is an atomic group:

> An atomic group is a group that, when the regex engine exits from it, automatically 
>   throws away all backtracking positions remembered by any tokens inside the group. 
>   Atomic groups are non-capturing.
>
> -- http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html

And, as Tim points out, atomic groups are *not* zero-width.

The true list of all PCRE constructs: http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

Comment: ...and it's not zero-width at all, so the page @MikeH-R linked to is incorrect.

Comment: @Tim Good catch, didn't notice that. Will include it.

Comment: @TimPietzcker ahhh... that explains why I couldn't find the answer on google. Thanks for sorting this out everyone. And thanks for the link to the pcre.txt, I was on that website, don't know how I missed it, must be one of those days!

Comment: No problem @Mike. Just realize that most modern day programming language's regex libraries often say they're PCRE, or PCRE compatible,  few of them support all the constructs outlined in the `pcre.txt` link (perhaps only Perl does?).

Comment: @BartKiers hmm... that's interesting, it would be interesting to build a series of tests to see how perl-compatible all perl compatible regexes are, I'm sure it could actually be built quite easily, you'd just need a series of regexes all testing a different construct and then for each language you'd just need the regex syntax and you could automate it quite simply.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you say that it's not documented.  Refer to [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Atomic+Grouping):

> Grouping can be made atomic with (`?>pat`). This causes the
>   subexpression pat to be matched independently of the rest of the
>   expression such that what it matches becomes fixed for the remainder
>   of the match, unless the entire subexpression must be abandoned and
>   subsequently revisited. In this way pat is treated as a non-divisible
>   whole. Atomic grouping is typically used to optimise patterns so as to
>   prevent the regular expression engine from backtracking needlessly.
>
> The `"` in the pattern below matches the first character of the string,
>   then `.*` matches `Quote“`. This causes the overall match to fail, so the
>   text matched by `.*` is backtracked by one position, which leaves the
>   final character of the string available to match `"`
>
> ```
> /".*"/.match('"Quote"')     #=> #<MatchData "\"Quote\"">
> ```
>
> If `.*` is grouped atomically, it refuses to backtrack Quote“, even
>   though this means that the overall match fails
>
> ```
> /"(?>.*)"/.match('"Quote"') #=> nil
> ```

Comment: good point, I neglected to check the ruby docs for that construct, I was looking for `\K` which (correct me if I'm wrong) isn't documented in their documentation.

Comment: @MikeH-R I usually refer to PCRE syntax by saying `perldoc perlre`.

Comment: Thanks, and from now on, so shall I. :)